# Is "Had have" form strange for you too?

Tags: grammaticality

Would you explain what is grammatical point behind this sentence? What does the author want to say? Is it correct to write like this in English? (Thank you in advance.)

> In the thirteen century, a number of political achievements cut Europe's overland trade routes to southern and north-eastern Asia, **with which Europe had have** important profitable  ...

Comment: As J.R. comments below, the  original text does not read  "had have" but **had had**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not only is it strange, it is ungrammatical to use **had have** in the sentence.

When the verb "[have](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/have)" is used as an auxiliary verb, it has to be followed by a past participle, not by a bare infinitive. The past participle form of to "have" is **had** and you have to use **had had** instead of **had have**.

If you contrast "I have just had dinner" with "I have just have dinner", it would be easier to understand.

Comment: Rathony is right. Unsurprisingly, this correction [matches the original](http://www.nich01as.com/toefl/reading/tpo17-1). That said, there are a few times where "had have" is grammatical (such as, *She better had have left the door unlocked*).

Comment: @J.R. are you sure about that example? It doesn't scan for me. _She'd better have left the door unlocked_ and even _She better have left the door..._ both seem OK, but not _She better had have left..._.

Comment: @terndon - I agree that example might be a little "off" (_She had better have left the door unlocked_ is probably a better wording). I was only trying to point out that most English grammar "rules" have a few exceptions every now and then. Garner says it better than I can: "A superfluous _have_ after _had_ is typical of **dialect**, and it sometimes makes its way into print. Those inclined to make this mistake often collapse the erroneous phrase into the contraction _*had've_." Perhaps I should have used scare quotes when I said "grammatical" in my earlier comment.

Comment: I have often wondered if we could entirely omit the clumsy 'had had' and just use one had instead. Most sentences still scan just as well with one had as with two. The above sentence could have been re-written as "...with which Europe had important and highly...". What do others say?

Comment: @tom You might find this [ELU question and answers](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2346/why-do-people-sometimes-use-the-past-perfect-form-of-a-verb-when-the-past-would) helpful. Since there could be no confusion caused by using just "simple past" **had**, I don't see any problem using **had** in place of **had had**. Using the past perfect tense is not always necessary.

Comment: @tom The past perfect is appropriate here: reference time, the time which the author is writing about, is the 14th century, and the author mentions commercial ties which *had run* from the prior 12th century up to the current reference time.